# Syntax in ARM assembly

Tags: arm

I have been doing some more reading and came upon this [link](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dht0008a/ch01s03s02.html). Over here most of the steps to implement a Mutex are quite direct and understandable... but a few things that I don't understand are in this snippet :

```
    BEQ     %b1           ; Failed - retry from 1  
    ; Lock acquired  
    DMB                   ; Required before accessing protected resource  
    BX      lr  2         ; Take appropriate action while waiting for mutex to become unlocked  
    WAIT_FOR_UPDATE  
    B       %b1           ; Retry from 1
```

present within the **lock_mutex** procedure. What is **%b1** and **%f2** ?? What do they relate to ?

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the assembler syntax used there, but if I had to guess, I'd say that `%b1` refers to a *backward* jump to label 1, and `%f2` refers to a *forward* jump to label 2.

Comment: it is what i thought of, but in ARM label should start with . and BEQ accepts just name, like `.loop BEq loop`

Comment: @Andrey, that sounds like details that are entirely assembler-dependent.

Answer (score 5):

`%b/f` are used to refer to temporary labels around the instruction. `%b` indicates "back" and `%f` indicates "forward". The number is the label to use. For example, the `2` you have in code would be referred to as `%f2` on the first three lines, and `%b2` on the last two.

Comment: We commonly use these in conjuction with macros.